# How to count active users on a specific page

Tags: php, users

I need to limit the number of active users on a particular page when there are at maximum 200 users on it. I've tried to document myself to figure out how it can be done but I can't find any good start point. Is it possible with php? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this a business requirement or a technical requirement? Once WordPress has served a page it will no longer know if a user is active on it, unless you've got AJAX callbacks or web sockets or similar added by a plugin or theme. Of course if you just want to know how many users are viewing a page simultaneously for whatever reason you could add AJAX pings back to your server from the page?

Comment: thank you. It's a business requirement and I would need to do it with php or some plugin... but I've never done nothing of similar.